# graphite + statsd, missing stats?

Tags: graphite, statsd, graphite-carbon

we use statsd as aggregator that forwards to graphite after 60secs.

i can see graphite filling the "stats.timers" buckets. but not all of the expected ones.

on the graphite machine:

```
graphite:/opt/graphite # find .../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting -name "*.wsp"
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/lastVisitors/mean_90.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/lastVisitors/sum.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/lastVisitors/std.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/welcome/count_ps.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/feditWelcome/mean.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/contacts/count.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/contacts/sum_90.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preContact/count_ps.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preContact/mean_90.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preContact/sum.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preContact/std.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preContact/count.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preContact/sum_90.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/fedit/upper.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preWelcome/count_ps.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preWelcome/sum.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/preWelcome/std.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/contact/count_ps.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/contact/sum.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/contact/std.wsp
.../xxx/desktopapp/members/contacting/favorite/median.wsp
```

looking at the statsd source code (https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/lib/process_metrics.js) i would expect the follwoing metrics to appear (each as own bucket) for each thing i time.

source:

```
    current_timer_data["std"] = stddev;
    current_timer_data["upper"] = max;
    current_timer_data["lower"] = min;
    current_timer_data["count"] = timer_counters[key];
    current_timer_data["count_ps"] = timer_counters[key] / (flushInterval / 1000);
    current_timer_data["sum"] = sum;
    current_timer_data["mean"] = mean;
    current_timer_data["median"] = median;
```

anybody any idea why for some i only get "count_ps" and for others i get "upper". does it take some time for graphite to process its internal statistics queue(s)?

statsd log says roughly 500 numstats / min are sent:

```
13 Mar 10:13:53 - DEBUG: numStats: 498
13 Mar 10:14:53 - DEBUG: numStats: 506
13 Mar 10:15:53 - DEBUG: numStats: 491
13 Mar 10:16:53 - DEBUG: numStats: 500
13 Mar 10:17:53 - DEBUG: numStats: 488
13 Mar 10:18:53 - DEBUG: numStats: 482
13 Mar 10:19:53 - DEBUG: numStats: 486
```

any help highly appreciated

cheers
marcel

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that for sparse data sets it seems to take a while for all the stats to show up in graphite.  I don't know the exact threshold, but it does seem from my experience to require a certain amount of data to be pushed into graphite for a metric before it shows all the different timer stats.

Comment: Also, Graphite has a rather conservative default for how many new stats you can add per minute (so it doesn't swamp the file-system in new files when accidents occur). When we add a lot of new metrics, it may take well over a day for all the new metrics to appear.

Answer (score 0):

@marcel , did you configure `percentThreshold:`  in `local.js` of your `statsd`?
and to get "upper" metrics , first you need to ensure how metrics are being sent to `statsd`. 
eg. To utilize timers buckets of `statsd` you need to send metrics with specifying it's type  like

specifying the type of metrics as timers as :

`echo "xx.yy.zz:<data point>|t"`